# OnServerClick event not firing on some page

Tags: c#, .net

In the website I'm working on, there is a bug I'm unable to figure out.

The bug is the following.

I have two different pages (with different functionality/controls). Both of them include the same page header that include a logout button.

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <uc1:pageheader id="PageHeader1" title="XXXXX" runat="server"></uc1:pageheader>
    <!-- page content goes here -->
</form>
```

The button is the following (located in `pageHeader.ascx`)

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Log out" id="btnLogout" name="btnLogout" runat="server" onserverclick="btnLogout_ServerClick">
```

With a server side function `btnLogout_ServerClick` that handle the disconnection.

In one of the page, the button is doing its role just fine.
In the other the `btnLogout_ServerClick` function is never reached.

I tried to put a breakpoint in the `page_Load` function of both pages. They both start with a first passage with the `IsPostBack` value set to `True` but after going through the loading of every control on the page, the first one end up in the log out function, whereas the other starts a new `page_Load` cycle with `IsPostBack` set to `False`.

There is no trace of error/exception on what could cause this behavior, if anyone could give a hand, either in giving a solution or providing a way to find the problem, that would be welcome.

And I know that I could try to remove every control and add one at a time to see if they prevent the button from working, but both pages have numerous control and it'd be nice if I could avoid that.

Comment: Check what goes over the network in both cases in IE dev tools or Firebug

Comment: Well both of them seems to send the same parameters regarding that event. The response is in both case a 302 Found. The redirection is not the same. One of them target the new page (redirection done in the logout function). The other targets itself (well the form has no effects, due to the bug, so kinda logical).

Comment: Does it redirect to itself or just serves the request?

Comment: The second one redirect to itself. That explains why I end up a second time in my breakpoint with `IsPostBack` set to false.

Comment: So now you need to go hunting on what code is doing the redirect which as it seems occurs in the lifecycle before the click event

Comment: Seems like hunting was the right thing to do even if it was not due to another redirect. I ended up finding a component that's raising an error when triggering a server change. And that might be the reason why the code never went to the logout event.
EDIT: Seems like you were right. After debugging that event, I ended up in another redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use browser tools (IE dev tools, Firebug etc) to see if the posted data is the same in both cases. If there are any redirects check if other code is not doing redirect before the event is raised.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is the event handler for the button.  Are you sure it is correctly registered ?

Possibly related to [user control event handler lost on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260163/net-user-control-event-handler-lost-on-postback)

Comment: Well it appears to be registered in both case. It always go through the `__doPostBack` function with the `PageHeader1$btnDeconnex` string as a first argument and an empty string for the second argument.